# If A and B are bounded sets on R and $\alpha \in R^{-}$ and $\beta \in R^{+}$, prove that $\sup(\alpha A+\beta B)=\alpha \inf(A)+\beta \sup(B)$

Tags: real-analysis

If A and B are bounded sets on R and $\alpha \in R^{-}$ and $\beta \in R^{+}$, prove that $$\sup(\alpha A+\beta B)=\alpha \inf(A)+\beta \sup(B)$$

I need some help with this one, should I use the fact that $\sup(A+B)=\sup(A)+\sup(B)$ and $\sup(-A)=-\inf(A)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sup(\alpha A+\beta B)=\sup(\alpha A)+\sup(\beta B)=\sup(-|\alpha| A)+\beta \sup( B)=-\inf(|\alpha| A)+\beta \sup( B) =$$
$$=-|\alpha| \inf(A)+\beta \sup( B)=\alpha \inf(A)+\beta \sup(B)$$